# Generating a unique ID in javascript. Understanding this code

Tags: javascript, date, uniqueidentifier

Here is a code snippet i've come across for creating uniqueIDs in a script.

```
var now = (new Date()).valueOf();
var future = (new Date()).valueOf();
while(future == now){
    future = (new Date()).valueOf();
}
return future;
```

My question is, why use `.valueOf()` instead of `.getTime()` and is the purpose of two date objects and a while loop to avoid the change of returning the same values if called multiple times. Surely the chances of returning the same millisecond representation of the date are slim to none? Any thoughts?

Comment: You'd be surprised how much you can do in a millisecond these days.

Comment: MDN Date: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: How is that producing unique IDs? If you want to use the timestamp, just return it. Your two variables and the loop don´t do anything!

Comment: Just for fun I added `var counter = 0';` just before the loop, `counter += 1;` inside the loop, and `alert(counter);` after the loop.  I saw 131.

Comment: @DanPichelman: Just for fun I did the same, I got 2491... Are you using IE? :D ...BOOM! 4106

Comment: @DanPichelman: And what is that telling you?

Comment: The function is not something I specifically use myself. It's in the source code of a piece of software that I make use of. The description is **"Get a system unique ID."**

Comment: @musefan Interesting! I got 3961, although I also just did one that was 2! Using chrome.

Comment: @Amberlamps: The loop ensures than no consecutive calls to the loop will return the same timestamp. If this is all the function does, it would obviously be better to just increment a counter each time.

Comment: @Amberlamps - that musefan has a much better machine than I do!  My original comment was addressing the OP's comment "Surely the chances of returning the same millisecond representation of the date are slim to none?"

Comment: @geon Yes, I guess my code snippet doesn't clarify it's use. I guess it's more of a unique timestamp than ID and that does make it fit for purpose. It's used for a Document management system. each document has 5 keys (unique identifiers) if the first 4 tend to be quite generic data where a duplicate is likely then a "unique ID" or timestamp is used for the 5th to ensure it remains a unique document. If that makes sense

Comment: @geon: This is just a complete abuse of the `while` loop. Freezing the process when you can use a counter variable.

Comment: @Amberlamps: Absolutely, looping while waiting for the next millisecond is a bad idea. A Counter would be the right thing here.

Answer (score 1):

As you stated, the chance of getting back the same uuid is small - but not impossible. There is no real need to use valueOf instead of getTime. Also there are way better algorithms for generating UUIDS see https://github.com/pnegri/uuid-js for well tested implementations which are also time based.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use `.getTime()` method adding some kind of basic operation, such a pseudo-aleatory number generation added to the returned quantity in milliseconds. Simply because a millisecond is not 100% a reliable output, as Dan Pichelman said, "You'd be surprised how much you can do in a millisecond these days".